# Material UI Navigation, delayed response after I click on any button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and Material UI to build my college project and suddenly I face an issue that when I press button from Material UI navigation it will response after some delay . for example when I press on drawer toggle button it will show after 2-3 seconds  delay.

I am facing this issue with drawer toggle button, theme toggle button and user profile menu button

What I found is that click event on buttons (drawer toggle, theme toggle,
profile menu) will take more then a second.

when user click drawer toggle button then "handleDrawerToggle()" function will run, for theme toggle "handleThemeChange()" , and for menu "handleProfileMenuOpen()"

my navigation file is :

```
function Navigation(props) {
    const { window } = props;
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const { authState, authDispatch } = React.useContext(AuthContext);
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    // const [locale, setLocale] = React.useState('zhCN')
    const location = useLocation();

    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
    const container = window !== undefined ? () => window().document.body : undefined;

    // theme
    const light = {
        palette: {
            type: 'light',
        },
    }
    const dark = {
        palette: {
            type: 'dark',
        },
    }
    const [myTheme, setTheme] = React.useState(true);
    const appliedTheme = createMuiTheme((myTheme ? light : dark), zhCN);

    const icon = !myTheme ? <Brightness7Icon /> : <Brightness4Icon />

    const handleThemeChange = () => {
        setTheme(!myTheme);
    }


    const handleProfileMenuOpen = (event) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    // progile menu close
    const handleMenuClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
        setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
    };

   

}
```

[image: performance report]

Comment: This is... kind of a code dump. What debugging have you done on your own? Are there logs/events you can check? Have you done any performance auditing via the browser's dev tools to see what is holding things up? Can you create a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces this issue that we can live inspect and debug in?

Comment: there is no errors or warnings in console

Comment: click event is taking more then a second to process